# Swift - CoreData - How to fetch parent object of a child?

Tags: ios, core-data, parent-child, swift5, nsfetchrequest

My application has two tables-

1. MachineTolerance

- Machine Type
- Tolerance1
- Tolerance2

2. Machines

- Machine ID
- Reading1
- Reading2

[This is how my tables are linked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB9LC.png)

Comment: Hard to answer like this. How are your relationships set up in your model? Sounds like you might miss an inverse relationship.

Comment: I have added a screenshot. I am a beginner, I only know how to fetch simple requests. Here how to fetch machineType corresponding to the machine id?